# MonoDevelop Split Different Files

Tags: monodevelop

Is it possible to split the IDE view not for a single file but to view two different files, one on each split?

Answer (score 1):

I am using MonoDevelop Version 7.8.4 (build 2) for Ubuntu 22.04 and it is now as simple as dragging the file tab to the other side of the screen to split the view for two files

See this: [MonoDevelop split view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Ubw.png)

Comment: This works in many IDEs by the way, not just MonoDevelop!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not currently supported.

Comment: Is it still not supported?